# Caching lookups in MVC, default expiration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, razor

I am caching lookup data in my mvc application, I have the following code:

```
  // GET: Category Types 
        public JsonResult GetAuditGrants(int auditID)
        {
            AuditDAL ad = new AuditDAL();
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["AuditGrants"] == null)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["AuditGrants"] = ad.GetAuditIssueGrants(auditID);
            }
            var types = (IEnumerable<Grant>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["AuditGrants"];
            return this.Json(types.ToList());
        }
```

If expiration is not set, by default when does the data expire in cache? Is recommended and should it be stored in the webconfig for consistency for lookup data in my app?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, we can consult MSDN.  According to [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), adding an object using the `Item` property (or indexer) is equivalent to calling the `Insert` method, [whose documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bawy15w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> The object added to the cache using this overload of the Insert method
>   is inserted with no file or cache dependencies, a priority of Default,
>   a sliding expiration value of NoSlidingExpiration, and an absolute
>   expiration value of NoAbsoluteExpiration.

Your second question is really pretty application-specific.  The best practice is to profile your application.  If your application is experiencing a ton of cache-misses and your cache stays small, then you might want to extend the expiration sliding window by using one of the `Add` or `Inserts` overloads that give you that control.  In that case, storing your selected parameters in the app settings seems like a good idea.

One thing to remember about this cache, however: it is per-app domain.  If you have multiple web frontends, or even an IIS server configured to launch more than one worker process for your app, then you may not be getting the most out of your caching strategy.  In that case, you might need to use something that can offer persistence to multiple instances of your app.  We use Redis, but there are many other options.